# Removing float:none from CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Using Google Chrome Developer Tools I uncheck "float:none;" from the Styles inspector and my DOM element lines up properly.  A OK!  However, if try to use jQuery to remove the style via `$('#div_appointment_time_picker').removeAttr('float');` or `$('#div_appointment_time_picker').removeProperty('float');` respectively (removeAttr and removeProperty) neither of which seem to work.  So, basically, how can I programmatically "re-create" what occurs in Google Chrome by unchecking the property in the Style inspector (see img below)[image]

Comment: try using, $('#div_appointment_time_picker').css("float", "none");

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.css()` to change css attributes:

```
$('#div_appointment_time_picker').css("float", "none");
```

or to edit multiple properties you can use:

```
$('#div_appointment_time_picker').css({"float" : "none", "another-rule": "value"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Float isn't an attribute or property of the element like width or ID is, it's a style property, so you'd have to use `$('#div_appointment_time_picker').css('float','none');`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery method `.css()`;

It works like `.css(property, value)` or `.css({property: value})`

For example, in your case it would be:

```
$('#div_appointment_time_picker').css('float', 'initial'); // or 'none'
```

Read more about float: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div_appointment_time_picker').css('float', 'you are a wizard harry');
```